# Custom field name for json for a Pageable response, "content"->"data"

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

In my controller, it looks like below:

```java
@GetMapping("/report-authors")<br>
@ResponseBody public Page<MyObject> getSth(){ ... }
```

The response JSON is:

> ```
> {
>   "content": [
>       <MyObject>
>   ],
>   "pageable": {
>       ...
>   },
>   "last": false,
>   "total_pages": 163,
>   "total_elements": 3246,
>   "size": 20,
>   "number": 0,
>   "sort": {
>       "empty": false,
>       "sorted": true,
>       "unsorted": false
>   },
>   "number_of_elements": 20,
>   "first": true,
>   "empty": false
> }
> ```

The question is: How can I change the name of `content` in the response to, say, `data`? The JSON I want to look like this:

> ```
> {
>   "data": [
>       <MyObject>
>   ],
>   "pageable": {
>            ...     
>   },
>   "last": false,
>   "total_pages": 163,
>   "total_elements": 3246,
>   "size": 20,
>   "number": 0,
>   "sort": {
>       "empty": false,
>       "sorted": true,
>       "unsorted": false
>   },
>   "number_of_elements": 20,
>   "first": true,
>   "empty": false
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I am aware of this is to create a custom class implementing `Page<T>`. You can achieve it for the sake of simplicity by extending `PageImpl<T>` which implements all the methods for you.

Let the custom class ignore the getter to the `custom` field using `@JsonIgnore` and introduce your own one instead.

```java
public class CustomPage<T> extends PageImpl<T> implements Page<T> {

    public CustomPage(List<T> content) {
        super(content);
    }

    public List<T> getData() {
        return super.getContent();
    }

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public List<T> getContent() {
        return super.getContent();
    }
}
```

Now define a simple simple GET mapping:

```
@GetMapping("/report-authors")
public Page<String> getSth() {
    return new CustomPage<>(List.of("A", "B", "C"));
}
```

And test it out to see that `content` is replaced by `data`:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:8080/report-authors
```

> ```
> {
>   "pageable": "INSTANCE",
>   "data": [
>       "A",
>       "B",
>       "C"
>   ],
>   "totalPages": 1,
>   "totalElements": 3,
>   "size": 3,
>   "number": 0,
>   "sort": {
>       "empty": true,
>       "unsorted": true,
>       "sorted": false
>   },
>   "numberOfElements": 3,
>   "first": true,
>   "last": true,
>   "empty": false
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It definitely work, but I am looking for a simpler way to do this